# add labels and legend in plotly express in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, plot, streamlit, plotly-express

the following is my code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st

#index is date
fig1 = px.line(plot_df2,y=['price','counting'],template="plotly_dark"})
fig2 = px.line(plot_df3,y=['price','counting'],template="plotly_dark")
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][1], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][1], row=1, col=2 
st.plotly_chart(fig, theme=None, use_container_width=True)
```

i want to add labels like price and count and legend like 'the dataset plot' to the code how can i do it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with the help of `update_layout`. This should add labels and legend to both subplots.

```py
...
# Add traces to the subplots
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][0], row=1, col=1, name='Price')
fig.add_trace(fig1['data'][1], row=1, col=1, name='Counting')
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][0], row=1, col=2, name='Price')
fig.add_trace(fig2['data'][1], row=1, col=2, name='Counting')

fig.update_layout(
  title= "Set Title",
  xaxis_title="X-axis Title",
  yaxis_title="Y-axis Title",
  legend=dict(title="Legend Title", traceorder="normal"),
  
  # Set first suplot title and axis labels
  title_text="Subplot 1"
  xaxis1_title="x-axis Title"
  yaxis1_text="y-axis Title"
  # Set legend for first subplot
  legend_title="Set legend Title",
  legend_traceorder="normal",
  legend_x=0.1,
  legend_y=1.0,
  
  # Set axis labels and title for second subplot
  xaxis2_title="x-axis Title",
  yaxis2_title="y-axis Title",
  # set legend for second subplot
  legend2_title="Set legend Title",
  legend2_traceorder="normal",
  legend2_x=0.1,
  legend2_y=1.0,
)
st.plotly_chart(fig, theme=None, use_container_width=True)
```

Comment: Dear @jamiu-shaibu i have 2 subplot your code works well for one plot not two have you any idea for subplot?

Comment: Hi @royaehazadi I edited the answer and you can give it another try to see if it solves your problem.

Comment: thanks Dear  @jamiu-shaibu i got error because there isn't variable title_text :-(

Comment: Sorry I misspelled `title_text` to `title_tex`. Which is the variable after `# Set first suplot title and axis labels`. I correct the spellings. I hope this time it works for you.